# How to obtain Google Docs document identifier in Alternative Runtime Docs Add-on

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

About a week ago the Alternative Runtime was released to the public ([general documentation](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes))

I am currently developing in Node.js. What I hope to achieve is that upon opening the add-on in a Google Document (or some button click), I can obtain the Docs document id of the document that is currently open and manipulate the document with the Google Docs API.

After fiddling, I managed to receive the payload for the `homepageTrigger` ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes#common_entry_points_for_gmail_calendar_drive_and_editors)). In the body, I do get multiple tokens but unfortunately, the `docs` field is empty. My first assumption was that when requesting the scope `documents.currentonly` ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-scopes#editor_scopes)) I would be given the Docs document id, so I could start using the Docs API and manipulate the document.

My second attempt for obtaining the Docs document id was to not use `homepageTrigger` but to use `OnFileScopeGrantedTrigger`. However, this required me to use the CardService. A new [Card Framework based on JSON](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes#build_json_cards) does exist for Alternative Runtimes, but I could not find any way of achieving the following with JSON:

```
CardService.newEditorFileScopeActionResponseBuilder() .requestFileScopeForActiveDocument().build();
```

([source documentation for the code above](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/editors/gsao/editor-actions#file_access_interactions_for_rest_apis)).

**TLDR:** How can I obtain the Docs document id of the currently opened Google Docs document with my add-on that is based on the new Alternative Runtimes?

Comment: Hey there, can you post the code you've been using for this "After fiddling, I managed to receive the payload for the `homepageTrigger`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's documentation is just the worst, I was wondering the same thing.
Below is the snippet for returning a JSONified response in Express that builds the prompt to authorize the document.

Basically, this is what helps you with defining your response object here:
https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/reference/rpc/google.apps.card.v1

```js
res.json({
  renderActions: {
    hostAppAction: {
      editorAction: {
        requestFileScopeForActiveDocument: {},
       },
    },
  },
});
```